# Differentiating various declarations in C

Tags: c, pointers, variable-declaration, function-declaration

While I was going through my questions, I found the these questions:

```
1) int*p;
2) int p(char*a)
3) int(*p(char*a))
4) int *p(void)
5) int*(*p[10])(char a)
```

(Please correct me if I'm wrong with my answers here.)

Q.1. is declaring a integer pointer variable 'p'

Q.2. is declaring a function p with a char pointer variable 'a' as argument.

Q.4. is declaring a void pointer(Maybe).

Can someone answer what these statements mean (and correct my answers if I'm wrong).
 Please answer as simple as possible. I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: [This](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) might be of interest.

Comment: [This](https://cdecl.org/) might also be of interest

Comment: I would highlight that this sort of question highlights the importance of formatting - `int* p(void);` vs `int *p(void)` makes it trivial to understand that the int is the pointer, not p

Comment: @UKMonkey Having originially learned from Kernighan & Ritchie's 1978 edition, I got used to writing it the other way, which I still prefer. Do you know, is there any logical sense in writing it your way, or is this merely a formatting preference? The mere syntax is of course identical either way.

Comment: @thb it's entirely formatting preference; but "is there any logical sense in writing it your way" well, `int *p()` might get confused with is `int (*p)()` - which you don't want.  In the same way, some might get confused between `const int p()` and `int const p()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q.1. Correct.

Q.2. You forgot to mention that the function, when called, returns an integer—so, that, in the program's body, one can write an integer expression like `p(a) + 1`—but, otherwise, correct.

Q.4. This one is tricky. Here you have a function `p()` which can be called with no arguments, but which returns a pointer to integer; or, if you prefer to say it another way, which returns the address of an integer. In the program's body, one might use it for example as `*p() + 1`.

You're doing fine. The usual way to read such declarations is

- rightward away from the identifier `p` outward, and then, once all modifiers have been exhausted to the right,
- leftward away from the identifier `p` outward.

Like this: 8765p1234.

The exception is if parentheses *around the identifier* intervene, in which case: 87(43p12)56.

The last gets tricky, because there exist some expressions in which the identifier itself is omitted, so you have to read it like 87(4312)56.

Answer (score 2):

Basic rules:

```
T *p;        // p is a pointer to T
T *p[N];     // p is an array of pointer to T
T (*p)[N];   // p is a pointer to an array of T
T *p();      // p is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*p)();    // p is a pointer to a function returning T

T const *p;  // p is a non-const pointer to const T
const T *p:  // same as above
T * const p; // p is a const pointer to a non-const T
```

Declarators can get pretty complex - that list barely scratches the surface.

Arbitrarily complex declarators can be constructed by substitution:

```
T *p;  // p is a pointer to T
   |
   +—————+
   |     |
   v     v
T *(*a)[N]; // a is a pointer to an array of pointer to T
     |
     +————+
     |    |
     v    v       
T *(*f(int))[N];  // f is a function returning a pointer to an array of pointer to T
     |
     +—————+
     |     |
     v     v
T *(*(*g[M])(int))[N];  // g is an array of pointers to functions returning pointers to arrays of pointer to T
```

The `signal` function in the C standard library probably has the most obnoxious declaration you’re likely to see in the wild:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

which reads as

```
       signal                                   — signal
       signal(                          )       — is a function taking
       signal(    sig                   )       —   parameter sig
       signal(int sig                   )       —      is an int
       signal(int sig,        func      )       —   parameter func
       signal(int sig,       *func      )       —      is a pointer to
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(   ))       —      a function taking
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(   ))       —        unnamed parameter
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(int))       —          is an int
       signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))       —      returning void
      *signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))       — returning a pointer to
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(   ) —   a function taking
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(   ) —     unnamed parameter
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int) —       is an int
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int) —   returning void
```

Answer (score 1):

Also :

Q3 `int(*p(char*a));` is like `int* p(char*a);`  and declares a function getting a `char*` and returning an `int*`

---

Q5 `int*(*p[10])(char a);` defines an array of 10 pointers to function getting a `char` and `returning an`int*`

Example :

```
int * g(char dummy)
{
  return NULL;
}

int*(*p[10])(char a) = { g }; /* entries 1..9 initialized to NULL */
```

Comment: (3) is the most interesting case, in many ways; (5) is the most complex.  I find the dismissal of Q3 as trivial in some  of the answers surprising.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sure `typedef int*(*fCharToIntPtr)(char a); fCharToIntPtr a[10] = { g };` is easier to read

Answer (score 1):

C declarations are written in [boustrophedonically manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon).

It starts from right all the time.

The 4 first declarations are easy, I write the last one only

```
int*(*p[10])(char a)
```

You start from the variable symbol, then do it right-left-right-left and so on.  All the time you start with right direction.

> (right) `p` is an array of 10 (left) pointers to

```
...(*p[10])...
```

> (right) functions that take a single parameter of type `char` and return

```
...(...)(char a)
```

> (right) pointer to (left) `int`

```
int*(...)...
```

So, `p is an array of 10 pointers to functions that take a single parameter of type char and return pointer to int`